# Sending Message to Specified Virtual Host in RabbitMQ by using MQTT Plugin

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt

I use RabbitMQ with its mqtt plugin. Also, there is a guest user who can reach multiple virtual hosts. For example, I want to publish an MQTT message directly to a virtual host **(/cse-id-1)** but it sends the message to the default one **(/)**. What should I do to send the message to the specified virtual host while using MQTT?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options for specifying the `vhost` when connecting the client, like prepending the name of the vhost followed by a colon to the username (format `vhost:username`), so in your case the username would be `cse-id-1:guest`.

See details and other options in the official documentation: https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html#virtual-hosts

Comment: I was hoping, it should be a way choosing vhost while publishing the mqtt message but I guess there is no option like that.